# Run JavaScript functions by logging into the url containing the id

Tags: javascript, url, tags

I want the user to go to this URL: `domain.com/index.php#index` This operation occurs:

```
$("#index").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("li#index").addClass("active");
    $(".loading").show(1000);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wrapper').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#wrapper').load("indexs.php", function(){
                $(".loading").hide(1000);
                $('#wrapper').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Can you provide more explanation?

Comment: yes of course. <a href="#index">Click</a> If clicked this tag => run java code , i want run code after go to this url index.php#index

Comment: You seem to be confusing `id` selectors with URL hashes.  Give your anchor the `id` value that the selector is looking for: `<a href="#index" id="index">Click</a>`  The jQuery selector `$("#index")` has nothing to do with a URL hash, it's looking for an element with the `id` value `"index"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `window.location.hash`. This could be implemented, in your example, by doing something like this, assuming you want the value of the hash to affect your jquery selectors.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(hash).click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("li" + hash).addClass("active");
    $(".loading").show(1000);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wrapper').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#wrapper').load("indexs.php", function(){
                $(".loading").hide(1000);
                $('#wrapper').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```